# How do scan a script for return values from a upper script in python?

Tags: python, return

```
import os
import pdb

os.system("ToBuildOrNot.py MSS_sims")

for output in os.system:
     if ToBuildOrNot is True:
         print "The MSS_sims Needs To rebuilt"

     elif ToBuildOrNot is False:
         print "The MSS_sism does NOT Need to be Rebuilt"

     else:
         print "error"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't invoke a Python script from a Python script by using system, which spawns a whole other interpreter.  Just import it.  Like this:

```
import ToBuildOrNot
needsBuild = ToBuildOrNot.run() # or whatever you call your top-level function
```

Since ToBuildOrNot.py is a script now, make sure the "main" function is protected so it doesn't execute automatically on import.  Most people do it this way in Python: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: i still am having trouble running the actual program "ToBuildOrNot.py MSS_sims" it still runs just ToBuildOrNot

Comment: You need to define a function like `def run(filename)` (in my example), and then call it with "MSS_sims" to pass in the filename.