# How scan for return values in python?

Tags: python

## !/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ToBuildOrNot

repoArray = ["MSS_sims","PCS_CCS"]

def main(argv):
    for repo in repoArray:

```
    needsBuild = ToBuildOrNot.ToBuildOrNot(repo)

    if needsBuild == True:
        print "\n",repo,"Needs To rebuilt\n"
        print "---------------------------------------------------------------"

    elif needsBuild == False:
        print "\n", repo,"does NOT Need to be Rebuilt\n"
        print "---------------------------------------------------------------"

    else:
        print "error"
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main(sys.argv[1:])

Comment: `needsBuild` / `not needsBuild` is presumably sufficient (unless you're expecting more than two possible values) - but do you have a question?

Comment: Yes my question is how do i scan the ToBuildOrNot.run('MSS_sims') for the true or false return value?

Comment: Why this question now - instead of elaborating on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323564/how-do-scan-a-script-for-return-values-from-a-upper-script-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by "scan"?  You've stored the result in `needsBuild`.  You can then use `if needsBuild:` or `if not needsBuild:` like you would for any other if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `==` for equality check not `is`, `is` is used for identity check.

```
if needsBuild == True:
    print "The MSS_sims Needs To rebuilt"

elif needsBuild == False:
    print "The MSS_sims does NOT Need to be Rebuilt"

else:
    print "error
```

Related : [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: Additionally, it's better to raise an exception for an error, probably, instead of returning `True`, `False`, or "something else".